# Are there any major advantages to using printf() over cout in C++?

Tags: c++, printf, scanf, cout, cin

There are obviously situations where, in C++ `scanf()` is preferable to `cin`, I was wondering if there are any situations where `printf()` is more practical than `cout`.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer, since I don't remember the details, but in a talk by a C++ standard committee member (he works for Facebook) he mentioned that he prefers printf() because cout doesn't work well with threads.

Comment: I'm curious as to what situations in C++ `scanf()` would be preferable to `cin`.

Comment: @DaveRager I find it easier to input and interpret certain strings using `scanf()`. Here's a line from my fist calculator program in C: `scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &op, &num2)`. `op` is a variable representing the mathematica operator (+, -, *, /), and, used properly, this can cut down on dozens of lines of useless code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do using `ostream` interface (so `cout`) is far superior to the old style `printf()`. First of all, it is **type safe**, so you won't get any segmentation violation when you mistakenly use a wrong formatting sequence.

An example. Imagine you have to print out attributes of the `struct stat` returned by Posix `fstat` function. The types of the attributes are defined using system dependant typedefs:

```
struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
    ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
    mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
    nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
    uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
    gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
    dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
   /* ... more attributes */
```

};

So things like `dev_t` are different types (typedefs) on different systems. You may find that on your particular system `dev_t` is equivalent to, say, `int`, and write this:

```
printf("dev_t=%d", s.st_dev);
```

and it will work on your system, but when you compile it on another system, which defines, for example, `dev_t` not as `int` but, say, `long`, then your code will compile, but crash in runtime.

If you use C++ streams and overloaded `<<` operator then stuff will always work correctly:

cout << "dev_t=" << s.st_dev;

Another important advantage of C++ streams is **extensibility**. It is not possible to extend the set of formatting sequences `printf` understands. In contrast, you can easily overload the `<<` operator to conveniently print objects of your own types.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Always!!!
In c++ It makes sense to always use cout over printf because it gives you type safety unlike printf.

Comment: no doubt there are advantages associated with cout but the fact that cout is not thread safe, make printf superior in some aspect :), so especially in debugging if you are  multi-threaded environment avoid cout etc...